# Traverse Tool Export error casues Import error "The file could not be loaded. Error on line 4" ArcGIS Pro 3.0.1

Tags: arcgis-pro, export, error, import

I always export my traverses so that if I need them I can import later I have been doing this since I started using Pro several years ago and also have done this for over a decade in ArcMap. I always update Pro whenever there is a new release and I am currently using 3.0.1. I normally get a file that looks something like this (when opened in Notepad) and imports great back into Pro, even if I originally created it in ArcMap :

```
DT QB
DU DMS
SP 678864.706  74.8416.581
DD N0-33-40E 2079.81
ect....
```

HOWEVER, I tried to import a traverse file that I worked on yesterday and it looks like this:

```
DT QB
DU DMS
SP 686992.127716 753223.537923
 D ??ƒ ??ƒ
 D ??ƒ ??ƒ
 D ??ƒ ??ƒ
 D ??ƒ ??ƒ
 D ??ƒ ??ƒ
 D ??ƒ ??ƒ
 D ??ƒ ??ƒ
```

When trying to import the traverse file I get the error

> The file could not be loaded. Error on line 4.

I have also notice that I usually enter the bearing then tab, tab, and enter the distance and that is not working either. I have to click in the distance field and type it each time. Note: I have rebooted every night, I have also been out of the office for 2 months, noted for possible missing patches.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to let those of you who use the traverse tool in ArcGIS Pro know that there are a couple bugs with the traverse tool. 1) If you export your traverse (to save as a text file) the Direction (bearing) and distance (chord length) are being populated with "???". ESRI is aware of this bug and will have a fix in 3.0.2. ESRI's work around was to revert to an older version of PRO. This was not an acceptable workaround for me since I have drawn several traverses in several different projects over the last several days. INSTEAD, I decided to create a feature class including a text field called notes, run the enable cogo tool (to add cogo attributes in the FC), save my traverse in my feature class "traverse_doodle_LF". This works as a short term solution. But I Prefer to save all of my traverses of Ordinance legal descriptions separately and name them after the ordinance. This way I can later import the traverse instead of redrawing the legal description. Hope this helps someone!!